# Execute jar cvf command by java code ( using Runtime.exec() method )

Tags: java, command-line, jar, command, war

I am using the Java code to execute a bat file to make a war file by the following java code

```
String command = "cmd /C start C:/processFolder/paas.bat";          
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(command);
```

which means it will execute the paas.bat file to do some jobs. There is a command within the paas.bat :

```
jar cfv xxx.war */ .
```

however, it does not jar all the file and folder into xxx.war. Does any one has the idea why this happens? Thanks！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command uses current working directory, which will be different from java program. You may change script to do a cd  and then call jar command.

```
 cd /d <path to folder where this should execute from>
 jar ....
```

Please capture output , error and exceptions(if any) from the command  and add to your question.

(note#1. It may be more useful to use tools like ant to do these task. The tasks in ant can be called from  java program using ant libraries.. 
Note#2 - Prefer [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)   to launch new process. )

Comment: I consider the ant solution, however, I want to try to pack war file without 3rd party lib.